# the ball does not reverse direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My last "if" is not working, I was using Transform.Translate but due to collision errors, I switched to RigidBody.velocity, now this last "if" I was using with Translate is not even showing when I use Debug .Log.
PointR and PointL are limiters for the ball and when the ball gets close to them, it has to change direction.
Thanks for the answers.

```
  public class Ball : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool isRight;
    public float speed;
    public Transform pointR;
    public Transform pointL;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
   
    
    
void Start()
    {
      rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(isRight)
        {

        rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed, 0* Time.deltaTime);
      
        }

        else
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(-speed, 0* Time.deltaTime);
     
        }
         if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            isRight = !isRight;
        }
        if(Vector2.Distance(transform.position, pointL.position) < 0.1f || Vector2.Distance(transform.position, pointR.position) < 0.1f)
        {
            isRight = !isRight;
            Debug.Log("changed direction");
        }

    
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you know the distance gets that low?

Comment: What are the coordinates of `pointR`, `pointL` and the initial coordinate of the ball?

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your object is too fast Vector2.Distance will not be less than 0.1f since Vector2.Distance has no negative outputs. Your objects can overcome the distance without getting into the 0.1f range.

I suggest to use triggers that collide with the rigidbody.

It would also be a tip to move rigidbody velocity changes to the fixedupdate method, which is more accurate in physics detections.